# How can I merge duplicate rows in a single table?

Tags: merge, duplication

I have a table with duplicate barcodes (`barcode`) and carts (`cart`) and (`Quantity_counted_IN`) and (`Quantity_Counted_out`).

I want to merge all duplicate records that have the same barcode and cart number to show only one barcode for that cart number but `sum(Quantity_counted_IN)` and `sum(Quantity_Counted_out)` at the same time.

Example:

```
           cart   barcode         Quantity_Counted_In  Quantity_Counted_Out
 Row 1        1   610708542209                     -7                    20
 Row 2        1   610708542209                     -4                    16
 Row 3        2   610708542209                     -3                    17
```

I want it to read:

```
 Row 1        1   610708542209                    -11                    36 
 Row 2        2   610708542209                     -3                    17
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This is what's known as an aggregate query,

```
SELECT cart, barcode,
       SUM(counted_in) AS counted_in,
       SUM(counted_out) AS counted_out
FROM tbl
GROUP BY cart, barcode;
```

Using `GROUP BY` like this returns one record for every unique occurrence of (cart, barcode) and the totals of counted_in and counted_out for each.

Answer (score 1):

Unless i missed anything maybe(not tested) //WORKS only with SqlServer >=2005

something like this

```
with CTE as
(
select barcode, sum(counted_in) as counted_in,sum(counted_out) as counted_out
from tbl
group by barcode
)
select (select top 1 cart from tbl where barcode=cte.barcode) as cart, 
barcode,counted_in,counted_out
from cte;
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing with the correlated subquery?

Comment: I Thought , that even he have a same cart with diferent Barcode , the agregate was by barcode not by cart+barcode. Since the question was so simple your answer is absolutely right :-)

Comment: Please also add that the query will work in SQL Server only (due to the `TOP`). The OP has not tagged the question with a DBMS.